# Magento 2.3.2 Add to cart not working even with 127.0.0.1

Tags: magento2, addtocart, php-7

I have installed fresh **Magento 2.3.2**, but add to cart is not working even I have changed the secure and unsecure base url in **core_config_data** table from **http://localhost/magento2/** to **http://127.0.0.1/magento2** .
There is not showing any error in browser console also.

Below are the details of environment I am using to run **Magento 2.3.2**:

**OS:** Ubuntu 19.10

**PHP version:** 7.2.31

**Mysql version:** 5.7.30

**Browser:** Google Chrome / Firefox

Please find the screenshot below for the reference.

- *Mysql version*

[image]

- *PHP Info*

[image]

- *Database core_config_data table:*

[image]

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

- *Debug log*

[image]

- *System log*

[image]

Comment: remove `var/cache` and `var/view_preprocessed` folder and run all commands again

Comment: Are you able to see any error in your logs, try to set the developer mode and check the network for request and response, more more error info uncomment error reporting from Bootstrap file and share error with us for more detail analysis.

Comment: @MohitPatel, Thanks for the reply, I did the same but issue is still there. I run the the below commands sequentially.
rm -rf var/cache/ generated/ pub/static/frontend/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento c:f
chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/

Comment: you try to setup , deploy and reindex command

Comment: Hello @AshishRanade, Thanks for the support, I did the same as you instructed. I set the mode to developer, uncommented the ini_set('display_errors', 1); but still not fixed.

Please find the log files screenshot update above.

Comment: @MohitPatel, deploy and reindex is also not work for me.

Comment: Hello guys, Finally the issue is fixed, as I found the error in /var/log/apache2/error.log, Call to undefined function Magento\InventorySales\Model\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition\bccomp(), so I installed bcmath sudo apt install php7.2-bcmath

Comment: Thanks all for the support.

Comment: did you checked in any other browser rather than chrome

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use x-debug to understand if php is called at the time of clicking on the add to cart button.

Also for debugging on magento 2 frontend I suggest you install this package that helps you understand how the frontend part magento 2 is structured.

If even so you can't find the solution I would move to the nginx / apache side checks to find out if there is an incorrect configuration of the redirect settings.

Have you installed varnish? In that case you should also check the varnish.vcl settings

Cheers